# method to check if form is full screen?

Tags: c#

how do i write a method which detects if my form is full screen or not and if not to make it full screen?
this has to take place at form load.

This method works only in a fullScreenToolStripMenuItem_Click event

```
class FullScreen
{
public void EnterFullScreenMode(Form targetForm)
{
    targetForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
    targetForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    targetForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
}

public void LeaveFullScreenMode(Form targetForm)
{
    targetForm.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.Sizable;
    targetForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
}
```

}

Comment: Very unclear why you cannot use the WindowState property.

Comment: Did you try to use form resize event?

Comment: Try setting on Form.Shown event

Comment: @Scarecrow - put targetForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized; during load event of the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that `WindowState` is only set after the `Load` event and therefore overrides what you set it to be, try setting it on the Form.Shown event.